# AngularJS ng-repeat query filter not show for nested object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have the following data,  how to query string under `"talent"`?

I used `ng-Repeat='friend in friends'`, but it can't search the data under `talent`.

For example: When I type `piano`, I expect it show the `John` node.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example98-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="">
  <div ng-init='friends = {
    "John-JqI-o4tusIKK1psPJw4": {
        "habits": "guitar",
        "job": "teacher",
        "name": "John",
        "talents": {
            "aaa": {
                "rating": "high",
                "talent": "piano"
            },
            "bbb": {
                "rating": "beginner",
                "talent": "playing"
            }
        }
    },
    "Peter-JqI9Svtr2fQLyJoMmyZ": {
        "habits": "reading",
        "job": "student",
        "name": "Peter",
        "talents": {
            "ccc": {
                "rating": "beginner",
                "talent": "CAM"
            },
            "ddd": {
                "rating": "advanced",
                "talent": "Typing"
            }
        }
    }
}'></div>

  <label>Search:
    <input ng-model="searchText">
  </label>
  <table id="searchTextResults">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>talents</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.talents}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Edit: I have restore the hash key to `Peter` node.

Comment: The filter filter works on an array, not on an object https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: @NexusDuck Thanks, I think I have to figure out a way to flat the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter filter works on an array, not on objects, see the docs for that: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

As you can see, converting this to an array works as intended:

http://plnkr.co/edit/rAQrt0jKB5VgcEHEIi45?p=preview

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example98-production</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
<body ng-app="">
  <div ng-init='friends = [{
    "habits": "guitar",
    "job": "teacher",
    "name": "John",
    "talents": {
        "aaa": {
            "rating": "high",
            "talent": "piano"
        },
        "bbb": {
            "rating": "beginner",
            "talent": "playing"
        }
    }
},
   {
    "habits": "reading",
    "job": "student",
    "name": "Peter",
    "talents": {
        "ccc": {
            "rating": "beginner",
            "talent": "CAM"
        },
        "ddd": {
            "rating": "advanced",
            "talent": "Typing"
        }
    }
}]'></div>

<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>talents</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
<td>{{friend.name}}</td>
<td>{{friend.talents}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

I've removed both keys"John" and "Peter", I wouldn't recommend using names as property keys, it's hard to reference them in an ng-repeat since both objects have a different key ("John" and "Peter"), so they're technically not the same kind of object

EDIT#2:

If you really want to have 2 different keys, you could use this (extremely ugly) solution:

http://plnkr.co/edit/rAQrt0jKB5VgcEHEIi45?p=preview

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example98-production</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
<body ng-app="">
  <div ng-init='friends = [{
  "John" : {
    "habits": "guitar",
    "job": "teacher",
    "name": "John",
    "talents": {
        "aaa": {
            "rating": "high",
            "talent": "piano"
        },
        "bbb": {
            "rating": "beginner",
            "talent": "playing"
        }
    }
}},
{"Peter" : {
    "habits": "reading",
    "job": "student",
    "name": "Peter",
    "talents": {
        "ccc": {
            "rating": "beginner",
            "talent": "CAM"
        },
        "ddd": {
            "rating": "advanced",
            "talent": "Typing"
        }
    }
}}]'></div>

<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>talents</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
<td ng-if="friend.John">{{friend.John.name}}</td>
<td ng-if="friend.Peter">{{friend.Peter.name}}</td>
<td ng-if="friend.John">{{friend.John.talents}}</td>
<td ng-if="friend.Peter">{{friend.Peter.talents}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would have used the opportunity to also define `friends` in a controller rather than this hideous definition in `ng-init` :)

Comment: true, but I think OP is just tweaking the example from the angular docs (where it's also defined in ng-init)

Comment: That is ... terrible :)

Comment: @NexusDuck Thanks for quick reply! But what if my data structure do have a `John` node and `Peter` node and cannot be removed?

Comment: @NewDev It is, but since it's just an example and it's slightly faster to write I understand the reasoning behind it :)

Comment: @Aaron What do you mean more specifically? Your 2 objects have a name property already where you can store the names John and Peter

Comment: @NexusDuck That data was retrieved from an api call. So I cannot delete the `Peter` and `John`(I have simplified that name from another name -Hash string).

Comment: @Aaron See my answer, your objects are technically not the same kind of object so using them in an ng-repeat, you'll have to reference them with a different key (i.e. friend.John.name and friend.Peter.name), which is probably not something you'd want to do

Comment: @NexusDuck thanks for the EDIT 2 answer. It's some kind ugly, and I have many User names , so the combination of these names would be horrible.